# Create function to return results from multiple queries

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I am struggling to write a function to return data from more than 1 table in Postgres

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.device (
    deviceid uuid NOT NULL,
    serialnumber character varying(255),
    productcode character varying(255),
    description character varying(255),
    softwareversion character varying(255),
    build character varying(255),
    builddate timestamp with time zone,
    assigned boolean,
    groupid uuid,
    updateddatetime timestamp with time zone,
    restartpointerno integer,
    deviceconnectionindex integer,
    organisationid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT pk__device__49e123311461d246 PRIMARY KEY (deviceid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_device_organisation_organisationid FOREIGN KEY (organisationid)
        REFERENCES dbo.organisation (organisationid),
    CONSTRAINT fkdevice951246 FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
        REFERENCES dbo.groups (groupid),
    CONSTRAINT fkdevice_deviceconnectiontype FOREIGN KEY (deviceconnectionindex)
        REFERENCES dbo.deviceconnectiontype (deviceconnectionindex)
);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.device OWNER to postgres;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.devicechannel (
    devicechannelid uuid NOT NULL,
    deviceid uuid,
    groupid uuid,
    channeltypeid uuid,
    derivedchannelid uuid,
    channelid integer,
    channelname character varying(255),
    isinternal boolean,
    dimension character varying(255),
    symbol character varying(255),
    upper real,
    lower real,
    "precision" integer,
    conversiontypeid smallint,
    CONSTRAINT pk__devicech__b0754e8587c246f2 PRIMARY KEY (devicechannelid),
    CONSTRAINT devicechannel_deviceid_channelid UNIQUE (deviceid, channelid),
    CONSTRAINT fkdevice_devicechannel FOREIGN KEY (deviceid)
        REFERENCES dbo.device (deviceid),
    CONSTRAINT fkdevicechan248448 FOREIGN KEY (channeltypeid)
        REFERENCES dbo.channeltype (channeltypeid),
    CONSTRAINT fkdevicechan30310 FOREIGN KEY (conversiontypeid)
        REFERENCES dbo.conversiontype (conversiontypeid),
    CONSTRAINT fkdevicechan3820 FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
        REFERENCES dbo.groups (groupid),
    CONSTRAINT fkdevicechan92763 FOREIGN KEY (derivedchannelid)
        REFERENCES dbo.derivedchannel (derivedchannelid)
);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.devicechannel OWNER to postgres;
```

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_test(id integer, ref1 refcursor, ref2 refcursor)
 RETURNS SETOF refcursor
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT * FROM dbo.Device;
    RETURN NEXT ref1;
    OPEN ref2 FOR SELECT * FROM dbo.DeviceChannel;
    RETURN NEXT ref2;
END;
$function$
;
```

When I run this as follows:

```
BEGIN;
    SELECT func_test(69, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');
    FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";
    FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";
COMMIT;
```

I get no data at all:

But when I run the 2 `SELECT` statements:

```
Select * from dbo.Device;
Select * from dbo.DeviceChannel;
```

They do return data on their own;

How can I write a function in Postgres to use queries which return data from more than 1 table?

Comment: I'm betting `'Ref1'` and `'Ref2'`  are being folded to `ref1` and `ref2`. Try `FETCH ALL IN ref1;` and `FETCH ALL IN ref2;`

Comment: do you mean in the function or outside?

Comment: `FETCH ALL IN  ...` only exists outside the function.

Comment: ok but i was attempting to run it as follows:


BEGIN;
    SELECT func_test(69, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');
    FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";
    FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";
COMMIT;


Is that what you meant?

Comment: For goodness sake's just change  `FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";` and `FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";` to `FETCH ALL IN  ref1;` and `FETCH ALL IN ref2;`. Then read [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Never ever use UPPER case names for objects and never ever use double quotes " to shoot yourself in the foot...

Comment: I did that as follows:

BEGIN;
    SELECT func_test(69, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');
    FETCH ALL IN Ref1;
    FETCH ALL IN Ref2;
COMMIT;

And then got this error message:

ERROR:  cursor "ref1" does not exist

Comment: I tried your example, and it works like a charm. I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong about the naming.  I reproduced your original example and it worked. Are you working on the same database instance when you use the cursors as when you do the SELECT?

Comment: I am working on the same database instance 
and its really weird how when i run the select statements on their own ... i get data returned

but when i run the function i get no data at all?

Comment: you say it is working but is it returnning data? 

I have created the function in the public schema...but my tables are in the dbo Schema.

does that matter?

I am very new to postgres development

Comment: Did you maybe run the whole transaction in pgAdmin? It cannot display multiple result sets and only displays the results of the last command. And there is a bug on top of that  in current version 7.7: it shows the table structure of the last `FETCH` with no result rows if you execute all at once: `BEGIN;  SELECT func_test(69, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');  FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";  FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";  COMMIT;` If so, test in a different client. Like psql. And consider a bug report to pgAdmin: https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/new

Comment: What client are you using to run these queries?

Comment: im running the query in PGAdmin4.

My postgres database is version 16

Comment: I did run the whole transaction in pgAdmin and it displays columns from the 2nd and last command but with no data

Comment: Try running `BEGIN;  SELECT func_test(69, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');  FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";`   - without `COMMIT;`. You'll see results. Note that the transaction is open until closed in this case. So you can run `FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";` next while the transaction is open. Eventually run `COMMIT;` or `ROLLBACK;` to close the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The code works as is. Upper case spelling for the portal names is unhelpful, but completely legal. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

The issue seems to be with your client pgAdmin4. It cannot display multiple result sets and only displays the results of the last command. If you execute this code block at once, results from both cursors are discarded, and you only see the "result" from `COMMIT;`:

```sql
BEGIN;
    SELECT func_test(69, 'Ref1', 'Ref2');
    FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";
    FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";
COMMIT;
```

And there is a bug on top of this in current version 7.7: it shows the table structure of the last `FETCH`, but with no result rows if you execute all at once.

#### Solution

Execute each line separately to see results. Or use a different client like [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Note that the portals only stay open for the duration of the transaction. Run `FETCH ALL IN "Ref1";` and `FETCH ALL IN "Ref2";` separately while the transaction is open. Eventually run `COMMIT;` or `ROLLBACK;` to close the transaction.

#### Aside

When passing the portal names to the function in `refcursor` parameters, you already know the names and don't really need to return them. Just:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_test(ref1 refcursor, ref2 refcursor)
  RETURNS void  -- SETOF refcursor  -- noise
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
    OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT * FROM dbo.device;
    -- RETURN NEXT ref1;  -- noise
    OPEN ref2 FOR SELECT * FROM dbo.devicechannel;
    -- RETURN NEXT ref2;  -- noise
END
$func$;
```

And do you actually need this function at all? It's often simpler to just execute two `SELECT` statements, or call two (set-returning) functions.

Comment: Hey Erwin

Thanks for your answer. Yes executiing each line seperately enable me to see the results. 
However that would be great for our c# application that would be expecting the results of both statements

Im not sure if i need the function but what I want to be able to do is run 4 or 5 seperate SQL statements

for this whats the best method of doing this? Im very news to Postgres

Comment: @ChrisAsi71: Just execute separate `SELECT` statements Or create separate [set-returning functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-TABLE-FUNCTIONS) or [views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) if you want to store the query logic in the DB. Or hire a consultant. :) Cursors may be useful for huge result sets. I rarely use them.

Comment: Hi guys 

I got this working in DataGrip ...PGADMIN is too buggy to run this but it worked in dataGrip